# How to run .cpp application on .htm file?

Tags: html, c++

I've made a webpage on HTML and I want to run a .cpp application on it. With the way I've learnt to do it, the code is displayed.

Comment: Is using emscripten an option? https://github.com/kripken/emscripten

Comment: The only sane possibilities are to use something like emsscript (compile C++ to native JS) or use C++ server side.

Comment: It would be better to run your cpp application as a CGI (server side) program with an API for the JavaScript to talk to

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is ActiveX, which by default is not supported by anything anymore. Only Internet Explorer supports it, but even that needs to be specifically allowed.

But you'd still have to first compile the cpp-code and do quite a huge amount of programming work before you'd have an valid ActiveX -dll. Then you'd also somehow need to deploy it for all website clients.

TL;DR: No, no no no. Running C/C++ for web clients is no-go.

However, if you are looking for something like that website client should be able to invoke a C++ application at the server, this is very possible. You still need to have that application compiled for the server environment though. For small "run and get the results" -tasks I've found it easiest to use ajax to call php -scripts, as php can execute stuff on server.

Answer (score -1):

Signed Java Applets can run executables from browser, but it's not welcomed nowadays.